# Cancel loading page if in request will be detected "some words" chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to catch search request when client will search something and find certain word in this request ,if exists page loading will be stopped (Search will be Cancelled) ?

**UPDATE**.

manifest.json:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webNavigation",
    "management",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "*://*.google.com/",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    return {cancel: details.url.indexOf("://salom/") != -1};
  },
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: You must post the code you've tried to make it easier helping you.

Comment: You should have edited the question or you could give a link to something like pastie.org. The problem in your code is the nonsensical usage of `indexOf`. It should be for example `indexOf("salom")` or `search(/\bsalom\b/i)` (actually this will require a lot of thought and testing). Also make sure you know how to use the documentation or google the syntax and meaning of the javascript functions.

Answer (score -1):

`"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webNavigation",
    "management",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "*://*.google.com/",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}`
it was manifest json and background.js is

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    return {cancel: details.url.indexOf("://salom/") != -1};
  },
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: but not worked ,why ?

Comment: this is not an "answer" so don't post the code as an answer.

Comment: It worked , thanks again :)